# Rotate an image on iPhone only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How would one rotate an image using the following line of code but for iPhone only?

```
PhotoView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);
```

My app uses a UIScrollView. In the scrollView are thumbnail images. When a thumbnail is tapped, a segue is triggered to load an image in a new view controller, but for some reason, the image loads on its side on iPhone 4 (it loads perfectly straight on iPad mini)

I used the following if statement format to no avail...

```
 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
    {
        // iPhone, iPod Touch
     ...
    }
```

My question: Is there another way to explicitly rotate the image on iPhone devices only? The following line successfully rotates the image correctly for iPhone uses, but conversely erroneously loads it for the iPad.

```
PhotoView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);
```

How can one programmatically rotate an image for iPhone 4 only? Additional info: this is technically an iPhone app under build settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
}
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
}
```

Comment: for some reason only the last if statement is read? The parameters are completely ignored for the first if statement i.e. if I try to set the iPad image to not rotate and the iPhone image to rotate using the above excerpt, the compiler overrides the first command and carries out the last one on both devices/ Any ideas?